# How to connect truffle using HDWallet provider to Websocket-powered node?

Tags: web3js, web3-providers, hd-wallets

I am using `truffle-hdwallet-provider` to connect to the node that operates over https and it works perfectly. Now I want to connect to websocket-powered node but keep my HD Wallet provider. I cannot find how to do that. All I found is package `web3-providers-ws` but cannot find is it possible (and how) to chain multiple providers?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass an instance of the provider instead of a string as a second argument. So you can pass a websocket provider in:

```
const webSocketProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(...);
const walletProvider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, webSocketProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

In https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/index.js, it is hard coded to use HttpProvider

You would need to fork and modify this line of code:

```
 this.engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider_url)));
```

to instead:

```
 this.engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(provider_url)));
```

I will give it a try some day and get back to this thread...